# Android VideoView on PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-videoview, popupwindow

is it possible to use VideoView inside PopupWindow ? 
I tried everything but it seems not to work... The VideoView is shown but there isvno video inside it, the methond OnPrepared seems to never being called :-( 
Is it because it is impossibile or because I'm doing something wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Hello? I hust want to know if I can giveup using popupwindow for video.

Comment: Did you give up? Because I ran into the same issue on Android 6.0 and I am going to give up by now.